# How to hide button on desktop

Tags: html, css

I have a button on my website but i want it to be only available on mobile.
How can i hide it from my desktop site?

```
<div class="pull-right">
     <button class="button-menu-mobile open-left">
       <i class="ion-navicon"></i>
     </button>
  <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>
```

And here is the css

```
.button-menu-mobile {
background: transparent;
border: none;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 21px;
line-height: 60px;
padding: 0px 15px;
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am attaching a working code snippet, here if you go full screen, you won't be able to see the button.

**Working Example**

```css
@media(min-width: 900px)
    {
    .button-menu-mobile
    {
    display:none;
    }
    }
```

```html
<div class="pull-right">
     <button class="button-menu-mobile open-left">
       <i class="ion-navicon"></i>
     </button>
  <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>
```

You need to use media-queries for this purpose. set min-width according to your need.

```
@media(min-width: 900px)
{
.button-menu-mobile
{
display:none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .pull-right {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```